# Latex not rendered when viewing TCS-blog in Google Reader

Tags: support, blog, latex

When I view the Theoretical CS blog directly on the site, latex is rendered correctly, but when I view it in Google Reader I see only the markup. Can anything be done about that?

**P.S.:** I already asked the question at [their meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/), but was told to try here.

Comment: Just for the record, it's perfectly fine to ask such questions on the site metas, the devs and the community team also monitor those, you don't have to post here on meta.

Answer (score 1):

There's one question that seems related [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3743805).

Alternatively, I imagine (though I haven't tried), that you might be able to knock together a userscript/GreaseMonkey to load mathjax into GoogleReader (though it could be pretty involved, what with everything being crazy ajaxy in there)